# Using Parquet for realtime queries

Tags: parquet, presto

I'm trying to come up with a solution for doing realtime (maybe within 0.x second), and I'm going to use Parquet to store the data.  I want to use Presto and API to query the data.

My question is, since Parquet stores data in HDFS, where files are invisible until closed, how do I effectively achieve the near realtime query results?

The Parquet files must be closed in HDFS quickly enough, in order to let the query tool to see and use them.  But, that means I can't put too much data into each Parquet file, ending up with too many small files and/or not real-time enough.  Any better ideas, or Parquet is not a good format for realtime solutions?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to achieve this? I'm working on a similar project right now that requires near real-time querying but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Sorry, not yet.  I haven't spent much time on this subject.